# How can I get the current flavor while looping dependencies in android gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-build-flavors

We've got a huge project with 100s of flavors.  To help keep our Google play services in line I'd like to define a default version and then override it in flavors as needed.

So to for all our various dependencies to use the same version I've got this:

```
 configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            //specifying a fixed version for all libraries with 'com.google.android.gms' group
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms') {
                details.useVersion '8.4.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to define:

```
defaultConfig {
    ext.googlePlayServicesVersion '9.6.0'
}
```

then over ride it in my flavor:

```
myFlavor {
    // XXX plugin requires this older version
    ext.googlePlayServicesVersion '8.4.0'
}
```

Then use the variable version in the configuration.all loop.

Is there anyway to access that variable in the that loop?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this directly in your `dependencies` block:

```
dependencies {
  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:$ext.googlePlayServicesVersion"
  myFlavorCompile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:$ext.googlePlayServicesVersionOld"
}
```

Any project flavor dependencies set with `flavorNameCompile` will override the default `compile` dependency for the same dependency and allow you to override the version for specific flavors.

(I use `play-services-ads` only as an example)

Comment: Does the `ext.googlePlayServicesVersion` variable get overridden? I mean do you really need `myFlavorCompile` if the variable has the correct value?

Comment: Thanks, good tip.  I was trying to set them all for all gms dependencies though.  This is because sometimes a third party dependency will sneak in play service dependency and cause zip exceptions when the version is different.